# How to make only the second generic parameter optional?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a set of non-related objects, but I need to write a generic function that gets its values.

For example, given:

```
type Circle = {
  color: string,
  radius: number,
}

type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}
```

I need a generic function like this one:

```
getData<Circle>('circle-id', ['radius']) // returns type { radius: number }
```

But the closest solution that I got to do requires two generics parameters:

```
getData<Circle, ['radius']>('circle-id', ['radius'])
```

making its use bad.

Currently, my solution is something like:

```
const getData = <Node, T extends Array<keyof Node>>(
  nodeId: string,
  attributes: T
): { [K in T[number]]: Node[K] } => {
 // ...
}
```

How to improve it, avoiding needing to set the second generic parameter?

I know that it likely can be solved using curry, but in my specific case, I need to make `getData` return a serializable object.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBtoF4oG8CwAoKKJAexWIQC4oBnYBOAOwHMAafQhAQwBM4BXalQZ8AtgCMICNngC++fKEhQACpOrEGUTLgJQGnERCq16zaYU5Mje0RKn45efCQa0oV4ABFOwTlqgAPAByxNwQLFAAKlAQAB7AEAzc1FAAgghcIAEA1hAgxABmUCFhAHylABTseqEQAJLcxnSMrNU+zWJ8CYJR+ACUVFhQANoA0lCMUcPC4pIAunNUJRBjc1AyWqXY7AgQwHwImlgbnClDYxOakdO284vFtavrDvJ4Lm4FxMT+Ht6+AfBkGgIsMAOQkMgIUFzSrgxCoCAAWjg3FBIPBpHI0L6+CAA)

Comment: Typescript objects must be all inferred or all explicit. You cannot have some inferred and some explicit. But how would `getData<Circle>('circle-id', 'radius')` know that it's going to be accessing a `Circle` object at runtime? That would compile to `getData('circle-id', 'radius')`. If could also be accessing a person, there's no way to tell the function that. I would rethink your approach here.

Comment: I wasn't going to check it in the runtime at this function. I'm assuming that the given ID matches the type in the generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Alex Wayne is correct in that you cannot mix inferred types with explicit types, you *can* do so by inferring additional types from the parameters with the help of a lookup table:

```
type Circle = {
  color: string,
  radius: number,
}

type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

// This is what makes it work
type Lookup = {
  'Circle': Circle,
  'Person': Person,
}

declare function getData<
  TKey extends keyof Lookup, 
  TData extends Lookup[TKey], 
  TEntries extends keyof TData
>(
  // Set the type by setting the key of the type lookup table
  key: TKey, 
  nodeId: string, 
  entires: TEntries[]
): { [K in typeof entires[number]]: TData[K] };

// String instead of generic
getData('Circle', 'circle-id', ['color']);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBtoF4oG8CwAoKKJAexWIQC4oBnYBOAOwHMAafQhAQwBM4BXalQZ8AtgCMICNngC++fKEhQACpOrEGUTLgJQGnERCq16zaYU5Mje0RKn45eBeGgAZYsQDWfMFuzsoAHJ4ZDRAqhDUCHMg1QR1BnCVNQ1pR3xuCFROBGgAMz4GJGA4DSgrYAARTmBOAB4AgBUAaQgQKAgAD2AIBm5qKE824jyody8fFigm6tqO7t7+sY9vMABtFraAXSmmgFEGOjgIAa6evoGhkBGoRtnOfAA+AAoAq6pNkF3dBmJMgEluMYjmZprpeiVcoJbgcjic1lt8ABKKhYKBrZpQRhQRQQG4QxDw4TiSRbLYfe4YrZQGQAbnkeAq92ewUQUUCU0CSDZaAAtHBuBz0VzSORAlskbSgA)